# Selector on TextView does not change color

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-selector

I have a programmatically created TextView and added a color-selector xml file for it. In the selector file there is only one activated and a default state.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:color="#ff867f"/>
<item android:color="#c50e29" android:state_activated="true"/>
</selector>
```

But if I activate the TextView in the Activity it does not change the text color and is still showing the default color.

```
        tv_header_exam.setActivated(true);
        tv_text_exam.setActivated(true);
        tv_header_exam.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.exam));
        tv_text_exam.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.exam));
```

Do I miss something here?

EDIT:

I've also tried it with following selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:color="#c50e29" android:state_activated="true"/>
<item android:color="#ff867f" android:state_activated="false"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: It does not work. It only shows the text color of the default state

Comment: did you try to call tv_header_exam.setTextColor before  tv_header_exam.setActivated ?

Comment: Did you remember to asign the selector to the TextView background ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getColorStateList()` instead of `getColor()`.

If you support < API 23, you can use the helper method,

```
ContextCompat.getColorStateList(context, R.color.your_selector);
```

Javadoc of the getColor():

> Returns a color integer associated with a particular resource ID. If
>   the resource holds a complex {@link ColorStateList}, then the default
>   color from the set is returned.

JavaDoc of the getColorStateList():

> Returns a color state list associated with a particular resource ID.
>   The resource may contain either a single raw color value or a complex
>   {@link ColorStateList} holding multiple possible colors.

Comment: That's the solution. It works with getColorStateList(). Thank you